# How to get 15 minutes intervals from a datetime column in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column called kyc_updated_at (type date time, ex: 2022-06-28 18:45:00.000 +0000). I would like to split this column into 15 minutes interval in my final output. Something like:

| KYC_Updated_at | Avergae_decision_time | cumilative_average_decison_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8-815 | 0.15 | 0.15 |
| 815-830 | 0.38 | 0.265 |
| 830-845 | 0.45 | 0.3266666667 |
| 845-9 | 0.63 | 0.4025 |
| 9-915 | 0.7 | 0.462 |

Answer (score 0):

So truncation is what you are wanting:

Thus with this multi-column sql to show the building up of the answer:

```
select column1 as original
    ,hour(column1) || minute(column1) as pre_parts
    ,hour(column1) || trunc(minute(column1)/15)*15 as post_parts
from values
('2022-06-28 18:46:00'::timestamp),
('2022-06-28 18:45:00'::timestamp),
('2022-06-28 18:44:00'::timestamp)
```

| ORIGINAL | PRE_PARTS | POST_PARTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-28 18:46:00.000 | 1846 | 1845 |
| 2022-06-28 18:45:00.000 | 1845 | 1845 |
| 2022-06-28 18:44:00.000 | 1844 | 1830 |

Truncating full date:

```
select column1 as original
    ,hour(column1) || trunc(minute(column1)/15)*15 as pre_parts
    ,to_timestamp(trunc(date_part(epoch_second, column1)/(15*60))*(15*60)) as full_trunc
from values
('2022-06-28 18:46:00'::timestamp),
('2022-06-28 18:45:00'::timestamp),
('2022-06-28 18:44:00'::timestamp)
```

| ORIGINAL | PRE_PARTS | FULL_TRUNC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-28 18:46:00.000 | 1845 | 2022-06-28 18:45:00.000 |
| 2022-06-28 18:45:00.000 | 1845 | 2022-06-28 18:45:00.000 |
| 2022-06-28 18:44:00.000 | 1830 | 2022-06-28 18:30:00.000 |

Comment: Is there any way I can get my final output column to be like: 1) '2022-06-28 18:00:00', 2) '2022-06-28 18:15:00', 3) '2022-06-28 18:30:00', 4) '2022-06-28 18:45:00' ?